# I Fought the Law Quest bug - Can't Talk To River

Tags: cyberpunk-2077, ps5

I went to meet River at the Warehouse so we could investigate the Red Queens Race but when I arrived and got off my bike, the quest marker suddenly jumped back into town next to the Luxury Apartments. I drove  back and the Talk to River marker seems to be underground and theres no way to get go it. (the dotted line disappears when i get near and just leaves the Quest marker under a building).

I've been back to the Warehouse, cleared it out, gone down to the Red Queens Race (which has no one in it) and explored the whole area but the Quest Marker just sits at Talk to River and directs me back to the Luxury Apartments in Westbrook. I've also tried calling him but he doesn't answer.

Comment: Can you load a save and try again?

Comment: I have an old save but from the start of the mission but I've done quite a bit of other stuff since then since I do wander off at times. :(

Comment: I’d suggest making a new save of your current state, and replaying the mission from your old save. If it works, continue playing from the old save - if it doesn’t work continue playing from your newest save

Comment: I was debating doing that but in the end I just went back and replayed the mission from the start and carried on from there. On the bright side, this time through I won the 6th street shooting competition rather than coming second...